# Gentoo on VM setting IP Manually

Tags: linux, networking, ip, gentoo, init-script

I installed Gentoo on Virtualbox with the minimal image. This is the first time I am running gentoo. I need to do

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.10
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

everytime it boots on VM and then I need to start `sshd`. I've added sshd to startup with `rc-update add default sshd` But How can I avoid seting the UP manually each time on start up ?

Comment: How?  Maybe this is interesting for someone in the same situation. (You cloud answer yourself `:)`)

Comment: I added its in answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by doing

```
cd /etc/init.d/
ln -s net.lo net/eth0
cd /etc/conf.d/
vi /etc/conf.d/net
```

and write the followings in that file

```
config_eth0="192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 brd 192.168.0.255"
routes_eth0="default via 192.168.0.1"
```

then add it to startup

```
rc-update add net.eth0 default
```

Done

Comment: The [Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/) is your best friend.